# have report run at specified hour

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a friend ask me about writing a program that would allow data entry and then run and display a report each day at 11:00 am.

What is the best/easiest way to make the report run at a specified hour?

He wants something that can run on a standalone (laptop) computer running windows xp.  Most of my experience is with asp.net and c#.

Comment: Where is the data being stored? What's the input software?  What's the reporting platform? That will probably significantly inform what you do .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Task Scheduler can be used to schedule most anything.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383614%28VS.85%29.aspx

Scheduling in Windows XP

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569

Answer (score 4):

Windows Task Scheduler?

That said, in an ideal world you'll store the data and run the reporting on a server rather than a laptop. (What happens if the laptop is off-site/turned off, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Use the Windows Task Scheduler. That is exactly what it is designed for.

Answer (score 2):

Sql Express with Reporting Services. This will handle your database and your reporting. Reports can be scheduled or accessed on demand.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx